# Why won't upgrading from pip version 6.1.1 to 8.1.1 work?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, redhat

I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux (on AWS). Whenever I use pip, it warns me that my pip is out of date and that I need to upgrade it by doing `pip install --upgrade pip`.

But when I do that it seemingly has no effect and simply tells me the same thing. It's circular!

How can I fix this? See below

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Since the aforementioned pip install --upgrade pip` doesn't seem to work, I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling python-pip. When I did that it tells me it will install pip 6.1.1.-1.21.amzn1. How can I make it install the newer version??

```
$ sudo yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
5 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python26-pip.noarch 0:6.1.1-1.21.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===========================================================================================================================================================
Package                               Arch                            Version                                    Repository                          Size
===========================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 python26-pip                          noarch                          6.1.1-1.21.amzn1                           amzn-main                          1.9 M

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 1.9 M
Installed size: 6.4 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux what? There have been lots of versions of that.

Comment: First of all you are in a virtualenv. Virtualenv comes bundled with a specific pip version, so you want to upgrade virtualenv first. Secondly you need to activate the virtualenv before you upgrade pip, otherwise only your system will be upgraded, not your virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just download pip 8.1.1 from github then install it from commandline?

```
$ wget https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/8.1.1.zip
$ unzip 8.1.1.zip
$ cd pip-8.1.1/
$ python setup.py install
```