# `pip` doesn't upgrade itself

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I can't upgrade pip (9.0.1) to pip (10.0.1).

Running

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

throws

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO'
```

(this is *yet another* issue I will need to deal with...)

Trying

```
pip install --user pip
```

returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

and has no effect, i.e. `pip list | grep pip` returns `pip (9.0.1)`

Running

```
pip install --upgrade --user pip
```

returns

```
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1
```

but `pip list | grep pip` still returns `pip (9.0.1)`

I have learned [**not** to use `sudo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021993/9472676), so please don't suggest this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36411650/9472676) suggests to install by hand (more or less).  But I am worried of messing things up.

If you are suggesting to use a virtual environment, I am afraid this is one level of sophistication too many for me as I am still very much a beginner, and if something doesn't work the way it should I will find it even more daunting to figure out what to try.

Is there really no alternative than the latter options?

Comment: use sudo. for real.

Comment: you should really use virtualenvs, especially on a mac. you will find that takes way more expertise to do it without. for a mac user, i would also highly recommend to use pyenv.

Comment: @hop I have a rough understanding of what virtual environments are for, but I don't understand enough to see how using them will solve my problem.  Anyway, need to do my homework before asking further questions...

Comment: @Antoine: you're sytem is probably in state that would be very hard for us here to understand and debug. i'm marking this as off-topic, please don't take it personally. try asking on IRC (#python on freenode is usually quite helpful) or maybe at a local user group. for now, my best "guess" would be to clean up `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` (probably remove everythin there) and `~/.local/` by whatever means necessary and start over - at least with _always_ using `pip install --user`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would probably need a longer back and forth to find out the state of the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can "safely" delete everyting in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`, except for:

```
$ cat Extras.pth 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

You can do it from the Finder (it should ask for your Admin credentials) or in a pinch with `sudo rm` - carful!

I'd recommend removing *everything* there - which *should* get rid of any packages you previously installed with `pip` or `easy_install` - and only ever using `pip install --user` from then on or better yet use `pyenv` from homebrew to get Python 3 and use virtual environments from then on.

Comment: OK, I gave it /one/ try…